# Poblem Related to Sanity Studio

Tags: reactjs, netlify, sanity

I have an Problem realted to Sanity Studio bacause i have deployed my react app on netlify and connect that link with the Sanity Studio API Cors Origin How Can I Change the Data on the Schemas of That Project Without Opening My VSCode and Run the code again.

How I Can change or update my data on Website with sanity studio.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.